# How can i prevent unknown categories in OneHotEncoder in Columntransformer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a Columntransformer like this:

```
oh = OneHotEncoder(max_categories=10, min_frequency=1000, sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='infrequent_if_exist',
                   drop='if_binary')
sc = StandardScaler()
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
coltrans_ = ColumnTransformer(
    [("cat_process", oh, cat_cols_),
     ("scal_process", sc, scal_cols_),
     ("min_max_process", min_max_scaler, min_max_columns)]
)
```

When i use this to fit on a dataframe and then transform another i get the following warning:

```
UserWarning: Found unknown categories in columns [1, 2, 3, 6, 7] during transform. These unknown categories will be encoded as all zeros
```

Sadly it doesnt tell me which encoder throws this warning but it can only be the OneHotEncoder as the other ones dont use categorical features.

So it try to find out which columns make this warning appear:

```
coltrans_.transformers_
```

gives (i marked the columns i think throw the warning):

```
[('cat_process',
  OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary', handle_unknown='infrequent_if_exist',
                max_categories=10, min_frequency=1000, sparse_output=False),
  ['categorical_1', 
   'categorical_2',#<--
   'categorical_3',#<--
   'categorical_4',#<--
   'categorical_5',
   'categorical_6',
   'categorical_7',#<--
   'categorical_8'#<--
]),
 ('scal_process',
  StandardScaler(),
  ['other_1',
   'other_2',
   'other_3',
   'other_4',
   'other_5',
   'other_6',
   'other_7',
   'other_8',
   'other_9',
   'other_10',
   'other_11',
   'other_12',
   'other_13',
   'other_14']),
 ('min_max_process', MinMaxScaler(), [])]
```

I am not sure if the marked columns are the right ones, because i dont know if the list in the warning is zero or one based.

I thought with `min_frequency=1000, handle_unknown='infrequent_if_exist', drop='if_binary'` on the Encoder i should not get a warning. I know there are infrequent features and they should get the infrequent label.
Why do i get the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because of two events happening simultaneously:

- During `transform()`, the algorithm encounters categories that it hasn't seen during `fit()`.
- During `fit()`, the `'infrequent'` column is not created. As a result, the new, unseen categories can't be assigned to `'infrequent'`.

A solution is to set `handle_unknown='ignore'`. This prevents the algorithm from attempting to assign unknown categories to a non-existent `'infrequent'` column during `transform()`.